# Guake tray icon is missing in 20.10

Tags: gnome, icons, system-tray

I have Ubuntu 20.10 that I installed just couple of days ago. I haven't do any special modding so far. I've kept everything stock - kernel, Gnome. However, I installed Guake terminal, that works as usually except one thing. Tray icon is missing despite I checked "Show tray icon" in Guake Preference.

[image: screenshot]

Unfortunately, I don't know anything about tray icons in Gnome nor I found simple guidelines. So the icon is missing and I don't even know where to look to troubleshoot this issue down.

Any ideas?